# How to tell Coq that it's okay to remove the `n`s?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

one more question here. So, I have the following goal:

```
  n, m, p, x : nat
  H1' : n + m = double x
  y : nat
  H2' : n + p = double y
  ============================
  m + p = m + p + double n - double n
```

I'm trying to `rewrite` using `minus_n_n (double n)` but `coq` is not convinced that I can do that. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `m + p + double n - double n` is actually `((m + p) + double n) - double n` (*), and thus there is no sub-term of your goal of the form `a - a`. You need to rewrite with associativity rules for `+` and `-`, or find some other useful lemma. For example, I found

```
Nat.add_sub: forall n m : nat, n + m - m = n
```

like this:

```
Require Import Arith.
Search (_ + _ - _).
```

---

(*) You can confirm this with `Set Printing Parentheses.`